# My front-end container running on Amazon EC2 is getting error ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, docker, amazon-ec2, docker-compose

I have two containers on AWS EC2 instance and I run them with docker-compose. These two different containers consisted of the backend and frontend images of my project. When I run it with the DNS address + :3000 port on AWS, I can see the front-end page, but when I try to login in my project (sign-up endpoint gets the same error), I get an ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error.

So I thought there might be a problem with the ports.

- When I send a request from postman on AWS's DNS address + :8080, the
  backend responds to me without any problems.
- The cURL requests (localhost:8080) made in the instance's terminal to the
  backend work without any problems.
- However, the frontend cannot send requests to the backend listening
  on localhost:8080 in the same instance.

What am I missing?

Extras:

DOCKER-COMPOSE FILE

```
 version: '3'
services:

  book-portal-back-end:
    image: "ugurcanerdogan/book-portal-be:v1"
    container_name: ugurcanerdogan-bookPortal-be
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      - SPRING.PROFILES.ACTIVE=default
  book-portal-front-end:
    image: "ugurcanerdogan/book-portal-fe:v1"
    container_name: ugurcanerdogan-bookPortal-fe
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    links:
      - book-portal-back-end
```

Inbound rules of instance:

[image: Inbound rules of instance]

Comment: is CORS policy setup in your backend?

Comment: Yes, it is. It seems there is no cors error when I review the browser network&console. Also, when I run them in my local PC, there is no problem too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real problem here was my "login" endpoint. There was no really a /login endpoint (I was catching login requests with filters, I didn't have any login endpoints under a @Controller) so every request was being denied. I changed my JWT and login-register implementation now it works well!

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the Security Groups associated with your FE & BE instances Make sure your FE instance allows outgoing connections to the BE instance, furthermore you need to ensure that the BE instance will allow incoming connections from your FE instance on port 8080

Something like this:

**FE Instance Security Group (Outgoing) you will need the following:**

Type: Custom TCP

Protocol: TCP

Port Range: 3000

Source: External IP of BE instance or Security Group

**BE Instance Security Group (Incoming):**

Type: Custom TCP

Protocol: TCP

Port Range: 8080

Source: External IP of FE instance or Security Group

Comment: I have shared my inbound rules in main question. Can you help me in this direction ? I have only one instance that runs both of containers.

Comment: @uqi8 Ok without seeing how your instances are configured exactly I've update the answer which will hopefully give you a general idea

Comment: As I said, I have only one instance, and my security group allows connections from everywhere.